# Did God allow the meat as aliment to make human life shorter, after the flood?

Tags: genesis

There are people supporting the idea that one of the reasons for which the meat was introduced as aliment for humans is that God wanted to make the their life shorter (we can see the difference between people lives before and after the flood).

> *You may eat any moving thing that lives. As I gave you the green plants, I now give you everything.
>   But you must not eat meat with its life (that is, its blood) in it. (Genesis 9:3-4)*

Are there Bible verses to support this idea?

Comment: Is there a post Eden exile, pre-flood verse that suggests they were only allowed to eat plants before this? Or are we arriving at a conclusion based on an implication in this verse that it's not entirely necessary? God could simply have been repeating this to show that he provided for Noah and his descendants. After all,  it was these very animals that they just saved in the ark. Wouldn't you be a bit scared to go back to eating them when God just went through all that trouble to save them?

Answer (score 2):

No AFAIK. Also if meat-eating was the cause, why don't vegetarians live hundreds of years? On the contrary they have to [plan their diet very carefully](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vegetarian_nutrition#Potential_nutrient_deficiencies) in order to avoid deficiency diseases. Therefore I believe that meat-eating was allowed because vegetables could no longer provide the necessary nutrients for some reason.

Comment: I'm very grateful for your participation here. We're a little different from a forum, so do take the [site tour](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already. Answers are expected to have informed argument, cite evidence (primary and secondary), and not simply offer speculation. You may want to see [*What are we looking for in answers?*](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/520/3474).

Answer (score 0):

**Did God allow the meat as aliment to make human life shorter, after the flood?**

There is a view called "canopy theory" in which it is speculated that people before the flood could not see the stars. This is the "waters above" that were allowed to fall to earth during the flood.

> Genesis 2:5-6  And every plant of the field before it was in the
>   earth, and every herb of the field before it grew: for the LORD God
>   had not caused it to rain upon the earth, and there was not a man to
>   till the ground.   But there went up a mist from the earth, and
>   watered the whole face of the ground.
>
> Genesis 7:11  In the six hundredth year of Noah's life, in the second
>   month, the seventeenth day of the month, the same day were all the
>   fountains of the great deep broken up, and the windows of heaven were
>   opened.

The absence of something in the atmosphere that would distribute heat would provide the seasons we know today. Without refrigeration, a way to get through a winter is to store food as livestock.

Answer (score 0):

Let’s consider that using the Bible and no extrabiblical text there is no certain way to know that meat was consumed prior to the flood. Though there were sacrifices.

However we may be able to consider some passages and speculate.

> Gen 4:4  and Abel also brought of the firstborn of his flock and **of their fat portions**. And the LORD had regard for Abel and his offering

This is similar to

> Lev 3:9  Then from the sacrifice of the **peace offering he shall offer as a food offering to the LORD its fat**; he shall remove the whole fat tail, cut off close to the backbone, and the fat that covers the entrails and all the fat that is on the entrails

And the peace offering was apparently the only offering allowed to be consumed

> Lev 7:15  And the flesh of the sacrifice of his peace offerings for thanksgiving **shall be eaten** on the day of his offering. He shall not leave any of it until the morning.
>   Lev 7:16  But if the sacrifice of his offering is a vow offering or a freewill offering, **it shall be eaten** on the day that he offers his sacrifice, and on the next day what remains of it shall be eaten

So peace offerings could be consumed

The idea that prior to the fall no meat was consumed can be deduced by these verses but this does not exclude the consumption of meat.

> “And God said, “See, I have given you **every herb that yields seed which is on the face of all the earth, and every tree whose fruit yields seed; to you it shall be for food**. Also, to every beast of the earth, to every bird of the air, and to everything that creeps on the earth, in which there is life, **I have given every green herb for food”**; and it was so.”
>   ‭‭Genesis‬ ‭1:29-30‬ ‭

God did not strictly forbid the consumption of meat and the fact that God sacrificed two animals to clothe Adam and Eve speaks to animals being intended for man and not co-equals with man.

Again the Bible does not explicitly speak against consumption of meat after the fall and prior to the flood. But in regards to the verse concerning the shortening of length of years that doesn’t compute that meat was the cause. After the flood people continued to live for hundreds of years and were consuming meat and animal products.

The reason God shortened the life span of man to 120 years was to limit the number of years man lived without His Spirit

> Gen 6:3  Then the LORD said, **“My Spirit shall not abide in man forever, for he is flesh**: his days shall be 120 years.”

When Adam sinned Adam subjected all of creation to futility and corruption Romans 8. There was now no possibility flesh in its fallen state to inherit externality. Man was not created eternal, he would become eternal, hence the tree of life in the garden.

So as a result of the fall and the mixing of genetics with the fallen sons of God, the life span of men diminished, at God’s decision. By what means? Certainly there are natural explanations but I don’t see the need to go into Biblical cosmology at this point.

I think the answer is clear, God reduced man’s lifespan because he was but flesh (corrupted/defiled) and decided to limit how long a man can live without His Spirit and therefore His guidance. Especially since even with God’s Spirit men (the daughter’s of men) still chose to sin against God and align themselves with the gods (sons of God or the elohim) against God. And learning from their elohim counterparts all manner of knowledge both useful and destructive. This was essentially gnosticism.

So man proved to chose against God even with the Spirit of God in him and so God limits the lifespan of man.